# How to get the number of items rendered in a Flat list?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist that sends data to another component where the data got filtered, then the flatlist renders the filtered items. I want to get the number of items rendered by the flatlist (i.e the number of remaining items after the data got filtered). How should I do it, please?
Here is the flatlist

```
           <FlatList
              style={styles.scrollContainer}
              data={this.state.schedules}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
              horizontal={false}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Today schedule={item} updateSchedule={this.updateSchedule}/>}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
           />}
```

And the component that filters the data;

```
               {schedule.once && today == schedule.date ?
                    
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.toggleScheduleModal()}
                    >
                        <View style={[styles.listContainer, {borderLeftWidth: 4}, {borderLeftColor: schedule.color}]}>
                        
                            <View style={styles.time}>
                                <Text style={styles.timeText}>{schedule.stime}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.timeText}>{schedule.etime}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.title}>
                                <Text style={styles.noteText} numberOfLines={1}>
                                    {schedule.name}
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={styles.subtitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                                    {schedule.type}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.day}>
                                <Text style={styles.subtitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                                    Today
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={styles.subtitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                                    {schedule.teacher}
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    :
                   []
                }
```

The data got filtered and is rendered as expected. I just want to know how to count the numbers. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use the method `Children.toArray(children)` to count how many rendered items there are.

I couldn't figure out where you'd use it in your specific structure, but you'd need to pass the `children`prop to that method. Children, in this case, I believe would be the component you're filtering your data in.

Another option would be to filter the data before rendering you component, which then would just be a matter of getting the array length.

```
const filterData = () => {

  // need to define `today` here
  const filteredSchedules = this.state.schedules.filter(schedule => schedule.once && today == schedule.date);
console.log(filteredSchedules.length);
  return filteredSchedules;
 
}

<FlatList
              style={styles.scrollContainer}
              data={filterData()}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
              horizontal={false}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Today schedule={item} updateSchedule={this.updateSchedule}/>}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
           />}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this current rendered index.

```
 onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
```

}

```
 <FlatList
    onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged }
    viewabilityConfig={{
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
    }}
  />
```